# "no such table" in SQL Cipher android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

I try to protect my SQLDatabase against decompiling. I post this question at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55197238/how-to-protect-sqlite-database-in-android-studio). but nobody answered.
I try to use [SQLCipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/sqlcipher-for-android/).

DBHelper.java :

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static String DB_NAME = "test.sqlite";
private static String DB_PATH = "";
private SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;
private static final String PASS = "sajjad";
private Context context;
public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 2);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 15)
        DB_PATH = context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";
    else
        DB_PATH = Environment.getDataDirectory() + "/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases/";
    this.context = context;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
}

public void checkAndCopyDatabase() {
    boolean dbExist = checkDatabases();
    if (dbExist) {
        Log.d("TAG", "already exist");
    } else {
        this.getReadableDatabase(PASS);
    }
    try {
        copyDatabases();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d("TAG", "Error copy DataBase");
    }
}

public void openDatabase() {
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDatabase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, PASS, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

private void copyDatabases() throws IOException {
    InputStream myInput = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int lenght;
    while ((lenght = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, lenght);
}

private boolean checkDatabases() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkdb = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkdb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, PASS, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
    }
    if (checkdb != null)
        checkdb.close();
    return checkdb != null ? true : false;
}

public synchronized void close() {
    if (myDatabase != null) {
        myDatabase.close();
    }
    super.close();
}
public Cursor QueryData(String query) {
    return myDatabase.rawQuery(query, null);
}}
```

and load database to recyclerView in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
DBHelper dataBaseHelper;
Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<Info> arrayList = new ArrayList<Info>();
Info item;
private Adapter adapterMain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recy);
    dataBaseHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    try {
        dataBaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
        dataBaseHelper.openDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        cursor = dataBaseHelper.QueryData("SELECT name FROM dictionary");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    item = new Info();
                    item.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                    arrayList.add(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    adapterMain = new Adapter(this, arrayList);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(recyclerView.getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterMain);
}}
```

when installing the application, the app crashed. can help me?

Errors:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{ir.seljad.sqlitechipher/ir.seljad.sqlitechipher.MainActivity}: **net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such table: dictionary: , while compiling: SELECT name FROM dictionary**
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2974)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1724)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7000)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:441)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
     Caused by: net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: no such table: dictionary: , while compiling: SELECT name FROM dictionary
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:89)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:48)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:60)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1954)
        at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1840)
        at ir.seljad.sqlitechipher.DBHelper.QueryData(DBHelper.java:102)
        at ir.seljad.sqlitechipher.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1222)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
```

Comment: The exception clearly says the table does not exist.

Comment: "I try to protect my SQLDatabase against decompiling" -- that is not possible. "I try to use SQLCipher" -- anyone who cares to can still "decompile" your database, since your passphrase is hard-coded in the app. You can defend the *user's* data by having a user-supplied passphrase, and that is what SQLCipher is for. In terms of your problem, presumably there is an issue somewhere in `checkAndCopyDatabase()`, such as having an unencrypted database in `assets/`.

Comment: @CommonsWare   I don't know how to say what I mean. please download this [dictionary](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mobisystems.msdict.embedded.wireless.oxford.dictionaryofenglish&hl=en) and decompile it. can you access to words database? I writing a dictionary app and don't want anybody to see my words.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the underlying issue is that the **databases** directory does not exist, as such the attempt to open the database, when checking to see if it exists, results in an exception. The exception being hidden due to it being in a try/catch construct. The result is that an empty database and hence no table.

I would suggest the following:-

1. use the Context's [**getDatabasePath**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#getDatabasePath(java.lang.String)) to ascertain the path. *This eliminates the need for hard coding anything other than the database name (including build version variations).*
2. Don't **Open** the database to check the existence of the database, rather check to see if the **File** exists.
3. If the **File** exists return true.
4. If the **File** doesn't exist, then check to see if the **File**'s parent **File** (the databases directory) exists using the **File**'s **getParentFile** method. If the parent **File** doesn't exist then use the **File**'s **mkdirs** method to create the directory.
5. Return false.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55199382/sqlitelog-14-cannot-open-file-at-line/55201000#55201000) for example code.